# C# equivalent to Java RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, rsa, padding

I am trying to encrypt at string in Java and decrypt in C#.
I tried with RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING first and it worked like a charm, but now I'm trying to switch to OAEP padding, but I cannot make it work. The encryption works fine but not the decryption. The only things I changed was the algorithm name in Java and in C# I changed rsa.Decrypt(data, true) from false to true. Does it require more changes?

The exception I get is "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding".

My Java encryption method:

```
public byte[] rsaEncrypt(byte[] data) {

    byte[] cipherData;

    try {

        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(pubMod, pubExp);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return cipherData;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

My C# decryption method:

```
private string RSADecrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        const string PrivateKey = *the key*;

        const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
        const string CONTAINER_NAME = "Tracker";

        CspParameters cspParams;
        cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        rsa.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);

        byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(data, true);

        String decryptedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);

        return decryptedString;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be SHA-256 that's not working with C#. I changed the algorithm name to `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding"`, and it worked!

Comment: If anyone knows why this is, feel free to comment!

Comment: [SHA-1 is the default for OAEP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#appendix-A.2.1). The security of SHA-1 within MGF1 is not an issue, so there is not that much reason to upgrade.

Comment: thanks for your  answer
for use  rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml)
I have 'pem' key ,how to convert it to xmlstring or doyou know an other plan

Answer (score 3):

RSACryptoServiceProvider does not support OAEP-SHA2.

.NET 4.6 added RSACng, which *is* capable of OAEP-SHA2 (256, 384, 512).  .NET 4.6 also changed the Encrypt/Decrypt and Sign/Verify signatures a bit to be more scalable than a Boolean, and moved them to the RSA base class:

```
using (RSA rsa = new RSACng())
{
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml);
    byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
}
```

If your private key comes from an X509Certificate2 instance the new [GetRSAPrivateKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsaprivatekey(v=vs.110).aspx) method (also in 4.6) will prefer a RSACng instance; though the return type is deliberately not guaranteed... so if you must cast it you should use `as` instead of a hard cast.

Comment: rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256) output is diffrence with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding?
i want to use RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding algoritm in c#

Comment: @hamidrezaHeydari Yes, it’s different, because SHA-1 and SHA256 are different algorithms. If they both said the same hash algorithm then they’d be equivalent…

Comment: thanks,what about rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256) in c#  and RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256 AndMGF1Padding in java. In c# icant find MGF1 
thanks

Comment: @hamidrezaHeydari Those are the same. MGF1 is implicit in .NET.

Comment: for rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml); my key is Pem How to convert pem to xml string?

Comment: @hamidrezaHeydari if you have new questions, please ask new questions instead of commenting on semi-related answers for existing questions. In the meantime, consider searching for ImportFromPem.